Route all local traffic through another openVPN client behind a NAT
So I'm working on a very simple problem,
There is a web based cloud infra behind a VPN (openvpn), Lets call it A
ANd then there is an openvpn client inside my office (behind NAT ofc) with no possibility to port forward or anything, lets call it B. But this PC is able to make a VPN connection to A.
Now the problem we're trying to solve is, while travelling, one of out dev needs to access A, and logically they should be able to directly dial in to A's openvpn, but they are facing challenges by their ISP (UDP blocking, Port blocking, deep packet inspection etc etc), But they are able to connect to B, so a solution that seems feasible is to route all traffic via B and which is transparent for A
It should be as if C is sitting in office PC B.
I've been reading up on this for some time.
Things I've looked into.

Have a common openvpn server and then make rules configurations on B to route
Have some sort of reverse tunnel b/w B & C while B is connected to A via openVPN
Have looked into hamachi

Things that we control:

B (sudo access)
C (sudo access)

Things out of our control:

A's everything
B's NAT
C's ISP
No dedicated IP for B & C
No portforwarding for B & C

What should be the easiest solution for this usecase, best is if there is little to no config involved( paid service is no problem)

Does it have to be OpenVPN software? Particularly since there are better options out there (Wireguard being the favorite because of simplicity and speed ... and its ability to "cloak").

XY problem. Yes there are several ways to join VPNs, but ultimately they all depend on C's ISP failing to implement the security controls the security controls they intend.

@user20574 thats because they are able to dial in using teamviewer / anydesk, no direct connection. Right now thats how C is actually performing their day to day activity. But that to too laggy to any actual work done.

https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?p=121027#p121027
For L3 (TUN) mode, to route all the traffic via another client, all you need is:
server.conf
client-to-client
client-config-dir ccd

ccd/client_name
iroute 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0


But wouldn't this require the client to be accessible from outside, ot both B & C to be on same vpn server

Yes. How do you connect to B from C then? Which protocol?

Teamviewer / Anydesk.

First B needs to run a server so that C can connect to it. But IP Forwarding is needed,as OpenVPN itself needs to understand the routing, so add "client-config-dir ccd" to server.conf.
Then OpenVPN needs to know which client owns each network (needed if clients source IP address is different from the IP given to it by the vpn server). That is why you need to add the iroute commands to a ccd entry.
Do not forget to create a unique name (named as client's certificate) for file  client2  in the ccd directory. This file should contain the line:
iroute 192.168.x.x  (client subnet) 255.255.255.0
This will tell the OpenVPN server that the client's subnet should be routed to client2.
Next, add the following line to the main server config file (not the ccd/client2 file):
route 192.168.x.x (client's IP) 255.255.255.0 (it's subnet as applicable)
The Route controls the routing from the kernel to the OpenVPN server (via the TUN interface) while Iroute controls the routing from the OpenVPN server to the remote clients. Both are necessary.
Server config file will create a VPN using a virtual TUN network interface (for routing), will listen for client connections on UDP port 1194 (OpenVPN's official port number or TCP if applicable, please specify), and distribute virtual addresses to connecting clients from the VPN IP address subnet.
(If your OpenVPN server will be running on a single-NIC machine behind a firewall/NAT-gateway, use the public IP address of the gateway, and a port number which you have configured the gateway to forward to the OpenVPN server + Make sure DHCP client service is enabled.
Open VPN Server will scan client config directory which client-config-dir sets. Please see ttps://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-0/
If you config the gateway to run on Windows machine, since this machine will be forwarding packets, the OS must be configured to enable forwarding.
How do you connect to B if no portforwarding for B &C and are B & C in the same VPN?
